# amAmcharts/amMaps accepting values from user

Tags: javascript, amcharts, ammap

How do we use values from text-box in JavaScript in am-charts/am-Maps?
I get a problem when i try to accept values in textBox and use them in javaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when your chart is already initialized and you change the data provider ensure to update your chart by the validade methods, check those methods on http://docs.amchars.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart

If that doesn't help please provide a snippet of your code ;)